# Ayuda con SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien sabe porque sale asi y como solucionarlo?
ayer estaba trabajando normal con el pero hoy que fui a continuar ya no me deja...

Comment: Tenes el servicio de Sql Server levantado ?

Vas a inicio / Servicios , Buscas Sql Server y le das click derecho INICIAR

Comment: [Te he votado negativamente porque solo dices que no funciona.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2871/15855)

Comment: Hola Deiby, con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]** en base a este documento modifica tu pregunta, es recomendable ser especifico y agregar información necesaria!, saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias por la aclaración, la tomare en cuenta para mas "consultas" a futuro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisa que los servicio de SQL Server y SQL Server Browser en tu servidor se estén ejecutando, también puedes revisar si no se movió la configuración como puertos, y también revisa que te encuentres en la misma red del servidor

Answer (score 0):

Es probable que tu servicio SQL Server se encuentre abajo, por lo que te recomiendo que revises si está operativo. Para aquello, haz lo siguiente:

*Inicio, Ejecutar, escribir services.msc
Buscar el servicio SQL Server y su Agente SQL Server
Iniciarlos con click derecho, START*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*La otra opción, es ir a Inicio, Programas, buscar la carpeta relacionada con SQL Server, y abrir el SQL Server Configuration Manager, y ver en la pestaña SQL Server Services en que estado se encuentran los servicios*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ultima opción, en caso que todo lo anterior se encuentre en orden, revisa bien si estás ingresando de manera correcta el nombre o IP de la instancia y su puerto respectivo. En caso de tratarse de una instancia local, valida que esté bien ingresado el nombre del servidor, o un punto agregado solamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]